# Доступ к getAssets () из другого статического класса

Tags: java, android, activity

Он работает с моей основной `Activity` и моим фрагментом, но если я использую метод `LoadSound()` в `Sound` классе, то `getAssets()` не работает.

```
public class CarnivoreFragment extends Fragment {

    private int mCowSound;
    private View view;

    private ImageButton mCowImageButton;


    public CarnivoreFragment() {
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_carnivore, container, false);

        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {

            Sound.createOldSoundPool();
        } else {
            Sound.createNewSoundPool();
        }

        mCowSound = Sound.loadSound("cow.wav");

        mCowImageButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCow);
        mCowImageButton.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);

        return view;
    }

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.imageButtonCow:
                    Sound.playSound(mCowSound);
                    Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Cow", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    break;

            }
        }
    };
}
```

И мой класс "Sound":

```html
public class Sound {

    private  static SoundPool mSoundPool;
    private  static AssetManager mAssetManager;
    private  static int mStreamID;
    private  static Context context;


    public Sound(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public static void createNewSoundPool() {
        AudioAttributes attributes = new AudioAttributes.Builder()
                .setUsage(AudioAttributes.USAGE_GAME)
                .setContentType(AudioAttributes.CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION)
                .build();
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool.Builder()
                .setAudioAttributes(attributes)
                .build();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public static void createOldSoundPool() {
        mSoundPool = new SoundPool(3, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, 0);
    }

    public static int playSound(int sound) {
        if (sound > 0) {
            mStreamID = mSoundPool.play(sound, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
        }
        return mStreamID;
    }

    public static int loadSound(String fileName) {
        mAssetManager = context.getAssets();
        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = mAssetManager.openFd(fileName);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
              Toast.makeText(context, "Не могу загрузить файл " + fileName,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return -1;
        }
        return mSoundPool.load(afd, 1);
    }


}
```

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: Вы не создаете экземпляра класса и соответственно конструктор не отрабатывает и контекст не передается в ваш класс. `getAssets()` должен получить свой контекст для работы, если не через конструктор, то как параметр метода

Comment: @pavloff, автор его не создаёт потому что это и не нужно. Вызываемый метод статический.

Comment: @Streletz Это замечание справедливо, но оно не передаст в класс контекст, о чем я и говорил. Метод не получает контекста, его статичность тут мало на что влияет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если создание экземпляров класса не входит в алгоритм использования класса `Sound` (так как все поля и методы в нем статические), то ваши методы не смогут получать контекст (так как конструктор не отрабатывает), который необходим для работы метода `getAssets()`.
В качестве решения можно предложить передавать контекст через параметры метода, в котором он требуется:

```
public static int loadSound(Context context, String fileName) {
    mAssetManager = context.getAssets();
     ....
 }
```

Вызов из фрагмента:

```
  mCowSound = Sound.loadSound(getActivity(), "cow.wav");
```

Если экземпляра активити будет недостаточно для контекста `getAssets()`, то нужно использовать другие способы доступа к контексту. Более правильно - получить экземпляр контекста один раз при создании фрагмента и "подсовывать" его везде, где требуется, а не вызывать каждый раз метод его получения.

Comment: Получилось, спасибо вам.

Answer (score 4):

Дело в том, что у Вас не инициализирован экземпляр класса `Context`. Его инициализация происходит в конструкторе объекта.

Либо создавайте объект класса `Sound` либо передавайте экземпляр класса `Context` другим способом. Например, в качестве второго параметра вызываемого статического метода.